# Why does it take so long to retrieve the frontmost process via AppleScript?

Tags: process, applescript, delay, lag

I recently wrote a utility program called [WindowTiler](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/windowtiler/id439626225?l=de&ls=1&mt=12) which moves around the currently focused window using global shortcuts. I move around the window via AppleScript and use the following script to get the **bounds of the focused window**:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set appName to the first process whose frontmost is true
  set appWindow to the value of attribute "AXFocusedWindow" of appName
  set {w, h} to the size of appWindow
  set {x, y} to the position of appWindow
  set appBounds to {x, y, x + w, y + h}
end tell
{bounds:appBounds}
```

Over time I realized that my App reacts **slowly if not used in a while**. After measuring the time performance intensively I found out that the **second line** of the shown AppleScript is the cause for the slow response. Sometimes the script needed a whole second to execute (on an SSD, as far as I know it's even worse on HDDs).

I don't know why AppleScript needs so long to simply look up the frontmost process - should be a sole request to the Process Manager. Maybe you know why it is so slow and / or can tell me a way to make the script faster.

PS: I configured Xcode to precompile my AppleScripts, when I create my App ("Archive"). The compiled scripts are read-only.

Comment: I rewrote the whole question due to new insights I gained during performance tests. The answer below might therefore make no sense for you - if you are curious you can look up the older version of my question to understand the relevance of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this kind of lag in receiving Carbon-based event hotkeys. Have you added logging to the code to see when your hotkey callback is called? Is that actually taking several seconds, or are you perhaps taking several seconds to process it?

Take a look at [DDHotKey](https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey) for an example of how to do this well (or you may just want to use [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115730/dave-delong) code to replace yours).

**EDIT**

If you're having trouble after the program's been running awhile, you may also want to run it through Instruments. Make sure you're not leaking large amounts of memory or threads. That could give the symptoms you're describing.

**EDIT2**

Why not load the script and keep it in an ivar or static rather than loading it on demand? Even compiled, you still have to read it off of disk, parse it and build up the data structures. (Also, this question has drifted off of its subject. You should close it out and start a new question about Applescript performance. Otherwise it screws up people who are searching for answers later.)

Comment: In fact there is a simple logging statement (I pasted the code into the question). Could that be the problem? It's such a simple statement. Processing the event doesn't take that long, because WindowTiler responds quickly if just started / recently used - at least I don't feel a lag in such cases. Testing this problem is hard, since the program must idle for some time to observe the problem. I will try and run it in debugging mode and observe whether the log message lags as well, maybe I will add some time measurements.

Comment: I thought about using Dave's code, which seems to be very popular (already read very often about it). I wanted to do it manually at first, since I'm very new to App development and didn't want to include custom libraries from the start. His code looks very similar to mine, though.

Comment: And in your previous tests, you see it taking several before the log statement prints rather than after, or you've not noticed? NSLog() can be very slow, but that probably isn't the problem. I'd definitely want to see timestamps between when you think you hit the keys to when the hotkey fires to when the applescript finishes. Maybe you're getting hung-up in the applescript for instance.

Comment: I added some time measurements in the event handler method and the AppleScript part seems to be the cause. It's normally around 0.1 to 0.2 seconds, but if the program idled for some time the first call to the AppleScript part needs 0.7 seconds. Thanks for your suggestions, thought it was some problem external to my program and didn't think about some time measurements to ensure that I'm right! I will precompile the AppleScript part soon and check if that solves the issue.

Comment: Precompiling the AppleScripts didn't help against the lag, but improved overall performance. I added a little bit more information to my question (see Edit2). Don't know what I could do to improve the performance even more. :/

Comment: Hi Rob, I finally came around to rewrite my questions based on the new insights I gained. Maybe you can help me with the new one. :) PS: I didn't close this question, since it made no sense the way it was before and I don't like the thought of it being around for everybody to see without an accepted answer and stuff. Therefore I rewrote it. Maybe you can adjust your text, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you force the script to receive the process (and all its properties), then of course it can be slow sometimes. Especially when debugging. Better and faster is to get just the **name** of the process. The more properties a process has, the more gain will be gained by obtaining only the name. Also, the focused window of the frontmost process is always **window 1**.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set appName to name of first process whose frontmost is true
    tell process appName to tell window 1 to set {{w, h}, {x, y}} to {size, position}
end tell
{bounds:{x, y, x + w, y + h}}
```